# Add font-awesome icon to a series of buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I know I can specifically add a font awesome to a button like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Some text <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

But is there a way I can create a CSS class so that the icon is automatically inserted for all buttons?

Comment: I don't know the library you're using, but I make a class, add some padding to the right, put the image as a no-repeat background, and call it a day.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is with Glyphicon and FontAwesome. Add your unicode (found in the CSS file) in the content and create a class name that is appropriate for your situation or just add it to the .btn or .btn-default, but change the css to reflect that:

**FontAwesome: http://jsbin.com/seguf/2/edit ***

**Glyphicon: http://jsbin.com/seguf/1/edit**

HTML

```
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-plus">Some text</a>
```

http://jsbin.com/seguf/2/edit

CSS

```
.btn-arrow:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f054';
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 90%;
}


.btn-plus:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: '\2b';
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this in CSS with the [`:after` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content):

[image: End Result]

Firstly, remove the `i` element from your `a` element, then give your `a` element a new class. I'm going to use "chevron-right":

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default chevron-right">Some text</a>
```

Now navigate to [FontAwesome's Cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) to find out the Unicode ID for the icon you're wishing to use. In here we'll find the following:

> fa-chevron-right [`&#xf054;`]

This means that the Unicode ID of our icon (in hexadecimal) is `f054`.

Now we can go to our CSS file and add the following:

```css
.chevron-right:after {
    content: '\f054';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Note that I've replaced the `&#x` of `&#xf054` with `\` and dropped the semicolon completely.

Here's a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/64Lu594z/) showing both the HTML icon and the CSS icon in use together.

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS rules will target the `.btn` elements and then inject a `:after` pseudo element that will place the icon at the end of the button. Additional styling may be needed. Other options are to use JavaScript to inject the `<i>` element with needed classes.

```
.btn:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f044';
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 90%;
}

 .btn:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f044';
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```